# Connecting Two buttons in one activity to two other activities

Tags: android, user-interface, button

I'm trying to make a simple math game with two modes, addition and subtraction. I figured out how to create a button that will link the "Addition button" to the addition activity but I can't seem to figure out how to create a second "Subtraction Button" that will link to the subtraction activity. Here's my broken code:

```
package com.example.kirky_000.madmath;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button button;
    Button button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        addListenerOnButton();
}

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Addition.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
            button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Subtraction.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code just have some syntax error which is solved as per given code...

```
package com.example.kirky_000.madmath;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button button;
    Button button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        addListenerOnButton();
}

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Addition.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
});
            button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Subtraction.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second instruction to add listener is inside the first OnClickListener.

So the listener is never added to the second button. You code should be like this :

public void addListenerOnButton() {

```
    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Addition.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

   button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Subtraction.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have different click listeners for different buttons. Right now, you're putting the click listener for the second button inside the click listener for the first button. Separate them like this..

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Addition.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

 button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Subtraction.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
     )};
```

Answer (score 0):

Some points before the solution (those will help you for further coding).

1. Declare `context` after buttons declaration : So after `Button
   button, button2`, write :

   ```
   final Context context;
   ```
2. Always keep in mind : Always initialize objects in `onCreate()`
   method. So in `OnCreate()` after
   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);`, write :

   ```
   button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
   button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

   //then define context

   context = MainMenu.this;
   //or context = getApplicationContext();
   ```
3. Now `addListenerOnButton()` function will be like this (just replace
   `addListenerOnButton()` with following code):

   ```
   public void addListenerOnButton(){
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   Intent intent = new Intent(context, Addition.class);
                       startActivity(intent);
               }
           });

   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   Intent intent = new Intent(context, Subtraction.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
               }
           });
   }
   ```
4. Now what is the wong in your code ?

   Your **onClick listener** code is wrong...

enjoy the coding :) (and android :))...

Answer (score 0):

you can even do like this

```
public  void  mainClickHandler(View v)
    {
     switch (v.getId()) {
         case R.id.button:

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Addition.class);
                startActivity(intent);

          case R.id.button2:

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Subtraction.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

    }


    }
```